# Why does 'aa' < 'z' evaluate to True in Python?

Tags: python, string, comparison, string-comparison

I am working with string comparison in Python. Why does `'aa' < 'z'` evaluate to True.
Further, why does `'aa' < 'a'` evaluate to False. I tried explaining 'aa' is of a longer length than 'a' so it would be greater. But this reasoning does not work for the initial case 'aa' < 'z'

`'aa' < 'z' => True`
`'aa' < 'a' => False`

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html), [how to sort](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-list-sort-tutorial-examples/) and other sites, define and demonstrate string ordering.  As the posting guidelines tell you, we expect you to do this search before posting a question.

Answer (score 4):

String comparisons use [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) order. To put it in simple terms, it's the order in which words would appear in a dictionary. Your examples would look like this:

```
a
aa
z
```

And clearly `'a' < 'aa'` is `True` as well as `'aa' < 'z'`. If two words consist of the same character repeated several times, the shortest word would go first. For the rest, it's just the order of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

They're in dictionary order. Alphabetical order first, length as a tie breaker. Just like in a dictionary, `a` precedes `aa` which precedes `z`.

Answer (score 0):

I think,  you can help the function ord() to understand it.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/ord

If see your example 'aa' < 'a' => False first symbol from 'aa' have **an integer representing the Unicode character** **97** and result **97 < 97 => False**. If we see next your example 'aa' < 'z' => True. **Python see only first symbol** like this **'a' < 'z' == 97 < 122 => True**.

I hope I can help you!